# C# mysql view only specific columns in data grid view

Tags: c#, mysql, datagridview

Short and probably easy question, I don't want to view in dataGridView columnID and few more columns as there is no use of viewing that info.

I have a clear code, the **connection is open**, the data loads fine and the comment code (btw most common solution in google) gives empty table with all columns (no rows).

I tried so many things that I can't even list them there :(

Any ideas?

```
DataTable SqlDataTable = new DataTable();
MySqlDataReader reader;

MySqlCommand sqlCommand = new MySqlCommand();
sqlCommand.Connection = sqlConnection;
sqlCommand.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM table_name";

reader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader();

//while (reader.Read())
//{
//    string columnID = reader["columnID"].ToString();                        
//}

SqlDataTable.Load(reader);

reader.Close();
sqlConnection.Close();

DataGridView = SqlDataTable;
```

Answer (score 1):

First when U want view data in DataGridView U should set the data source of it's like

```
DataGridView.DataSource = yourDataTable
```

Second, if U want to hide DataGridView column, U most know the index of the column or the  name and then you can use this code
I assume the first column is ID
So

> By Index

```
DataGridView.Columns[0].Visible = false;
```

> By Name

```
DataGridView.Columns["ID"].Visible = false;
```